Running a multiple word search macro in Word
So I'm running this macro to find and highlight multiple words at once. However, I want to set it to find only whole words as it currently finding letters within words and highlighting them. For example if I wanted just "as" highlighted it would also highlight the as in "wasp". Can anybody help me modify the code for whole words only please?
Sub HiLightList()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFnd As String, Rng As Range, i As Long
StrFnd = "as,the,bold"
For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrFnd, ","))
  Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range
  With Rng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = Split(StrFnd, ",")(i)
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
Next
Set Rng = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


To search for whole words, add to your Find code the following line:
 .MatchWholeWord = True

Reference :
Find.MatchWholeWord property (Word).

Edit- Thought if I changed the setting in word would work like the formatting but didn't. Unfortunately that line in the code is there it just doesn't seem to work

To only find whole words, use the code .Find.Execute. Your code does replacement with its .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll.

If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).
